# Ordination Graph in R

Tags: r, plot

Before I begin, I am very much a beginner at R, so apologies if this is an easy fix.

I need to create an ordination graph with species labels and a key. I found the 'vegan' package which I believe is relevant. I've read in the table and attached it and also have loaded the package:

```
Ordination<-read.table("pHWTD.txt", header = T, stringsAsFactors = T)

attach(Ordination)

library(vegan)

ordiplot(Mean_pH ~ Mean_Water_Table_Depth)
```

After this ordiplot function, the console returns: "Error in NROW(X) : object 'X' not found"

I don't understand this because Mean_pH and Mean_Water_Table_Depth are variables, so unsure what is not being found.

Below is a generalised version of the data I need to plot (where each species will be represented by a graphical point with an abbreviated label e.g. Species 1 could be spec.1):

[image: Data which needs plotting]

Any advice, if possible, would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to call in an ordination for ordiplot. Please refer to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vegan/versions/2.4-2/topics/ordiplot).

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your comment. I have read through the page you linked prior to writing my question, but unfortunately, it didn't help me (probably due to the fact that I'm a complete beginner). I apologise but I don't understand what you mean by 'call in an ordination'.

Comment: "Ordination is a collective term for multivariate techniques which summarize a multidimensional dataset in such a way that when it is projected onto a low dimensional space, any intrinsic pattern the data may possess becomes apparent upon visual inspection". Read more [here](https://ourcodingclub.github.io/tutorials/ordination/).

Comment: There are many ways to run ordination, and in the documentation example, it uses `cmdscale` ordination method before running the plot.